# AES/Blowfish: random IV vs. random data at the begining

Tags: encryption, aes, blowfish

I have understood the purpose of the initialisation vector (IV) in encryption algorithms like AES or Blowfish (see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29))

But I don’t like to transmit the IV each time and would like to use the same IV every time (easier coding). To achieve randomness of messages with the same common prefix, I would just add an always new generated random byte block of the same size like the IV at the beginning of the message when encrypting. When decryption, I would just ignore/skip this first bytes.

Does this random data the beginning of the message provide the same security like the usage of a random IV?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography, without direct relation to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IV is essentially "block 0" for modes that mix a previous block with the current encryption. So a random block added manually is equivalent. For more information (and probably a better forum for such questions), see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/using-cbc-with-a-fixed-iv-and-a-random-first-plaintext-block.

Comment: Thanks for this really fast answer ;-)